# Thresholding and circle fitting in Python

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

So, the main idea is to fit a circle to a red membrane within the image shown below.
[membrane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46tEZ.jpg)

For that I made hsv thresholding to create a binary image:

[hsv thresholding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdcv6.png)

The codes are below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import measure, draw
from scipy import optimize

import cv2
# matplotlib widget

# load the image
#image = iio.imread(uri="image.png")
image = cv2.imread('picture1.png')


image = cv2.resize(image, (960, 540))
cv2.imshow("image", image)



plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()



hsv= cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.imshow("hsv", hsv)

plt.imshow(hsv)
plt.show()


# define range of red color in HSV
lower_red = np.array([160,50,50])
upper_red = np.array([180,255,255])
     
# Threshold the HSV image using inRange function to get only red colors
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

plt.imshow(mask)
plt.show()

cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
```

Then I found some code that I could apply to my problem, not sure but I think it tries to optimize the radius of the circle in the buble region.

```
image = image
regions = measure.regionprops(measure.label(mask))

bubble = regions[0]

y0, x0 = bubble.centroid
r = bubble.minor_axis_length /1.9
print(bubble.major_axis_length)

def cost(params):
    x0, y0, r = params
    coords = draw.disk((y0, x0), r, shape=image.shape)
    template = np.zeros_like(image)
    template[coords] = 0
    return -np.sum(template == image)

x0, y0, r = optimize.fmin(cost, (x0, y0, r))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots()
circle = plt.Circle((x0, y0), r)
ax.imshow(image, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
ax.add_artist(circle)
plt.show()
```

[output fitted circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9ru3.png)

Here it doesn't really fit the circle in the bubble since if you change the r parameter before cost function, the drawn circle size changes. Any ideas how to automatically find correct r parameter to fit in the buble membrane? (I understand the membrane is not a circle, but it is the simplest step before fitting an ellipse)

Comment: Perhaps you should put your membrane on a table that is not a similar color.